# "unsupported type for timedelta days component: str" error in Streamlit

Tags: python, streamlit

I am trying to create a web app using the streamlit library in python. I successfully created my Login page a day ago, but it has just stopped working now.

This is the error I get everytime I try to click on login:

```
    2023-06-22 16:49:05.548 Uncaught app exception
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\soham\anaconda3\envs\project\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 552, in _run_script
        exec(code, module.__dict__)
      File "C:\Users\soham\Documents\Coding\Ipsos Project\app.py", line 59, in <module>
        full_names, authentication_status, usernames = authenticator.login("Login", "main")
      File "C:\Users\soham\anaconda3\envs\project\lib\site-packages\streamlit_authenticator\__init__.py", line 200, in login
        return st.session_state['name'], st.session_state['authentication_status'], st.session_state['username']
      File "C:\Users\soham\anaconda3\envs\project\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\state\session_state_proxy.py", line 90, in __getitem__
        return get_session_state()[key]
      File "C:\Users\soham\anaconda3\envs\project\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\state\safe_session_state.py", line 111, in __getitem__
        raise KeyError(key)
    KeyError: 'name'
    unsupported type for timedelta days component: str
```

What is causing this error, and how do I fix it?
I can share my code if you need me to.

Comment: It's not clear from where that 'timedelta' is called, from inside streamlit or your code? Please share more

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error log, there seems to be 3 possible source of error:

1. `KeyError: 'name'` seems to suggest that the `name` key was not initialized by Session State and some portion of your code is referring to it but couldn't find it. See [this solution](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/keyerror-st-session-state-has-no-key-generated-widget-id-none-did-you-forget-to-initialize-it-more-info/39325/17) from the Streamlit forum for ideas
2. `unsupported type for timedelta days component: str` seems to suggest that the wrong data type was detected, can you figure out which one and adjust the data type to the expected data type that portions of your code is expecting.
3. There may be an [issue](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/keyerror-st-session-state-has-no-key-generated-widget-id-none-did-you-forget-to-initialize-it-more-info/39325/9) with `streamlit-authenticator`, which may require further digging into the root cause

Hope this helps!